# Strange and hard to reproduce redirect for Visualforce pages in LEX back to the loginpage since Summer'18

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, url, salesforce-classic

Since the Summer'18 release I'm getting from time to time, randomly, without any reason a redirect back to the Salesforce-Login-Page when I load a visualforce-page. When this happens, this fault is ongoing for a while and then the VF-Page is not accessible at all for that time.

Sidenote: we are Salesforce Partners working with several hundreds of Production, Sandbox and Developer-Orgs. I'm using multiple browsers in parallel.

- It does not matter how I access the page

  - with an existing and known-good link it can happen
  - going to Setup > Develop > VF Pages > Page > Preview it can happen
  - being in LEX or Aloha it can happen
- Login-log-of does not help
- Clearing the browser cache, cookies, session-storage, local-storage, index-db, everything, sometimes helps - **but not(!) always. This is driving me nuts, since I cant figure any clear pattern**
- Deleting the session under Classic-Setup > Security Controls > Session Management for ALL entries sometimes helps - but again not(!) always
- Sometimes restarting the computer helps
- Mostly not all browser are affected, so if it happens, only Chrome might be affected and Firefox not, sometimes all of my installed browsers are affected
- Sometimes nothing helps, but waiting for some hours or a day which is super frustrating.
- It happens mostly when logging into a new dev org with a new user or logging in an org with a browser which was long time in use for lots of other orgs
- It burns now regularly time for my team an myself

**I'm shooting totally in the dark with this** and I can't provide better information to reproduce this behavior. It feels totally random. But it's driving me crazy...

**The only thing I'm sure of is, that it has started with Summer'18. In the spring release this never happened.**

My hope is, that others here have similar experiences which we can share and find out why this happens and how it can be cleared or refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found an answer on this on my own.

In the setup, there seems to be a new setting under Security Controls > Session Settings - there in the second section "Session Settings" there is a checkbox "Lock sessions to the domain in which they were first used"

Now if I am disabling "Lock sessions to the domain in which they were first used" I can use my VF-Pages with no issues. Re-enabling it again, brings back the error.

Is that a bug or a feature?

[image]

Comment: I ran into the same issue. From my perspective this is a bug, because otherwise there's no way to properly access a VF page. Since you're always redirected into the pages namespace (or "c"), you're changing domains and thus loosing the session. @Uwe Heim: Did you ever find a workaround and keep the setting enabled?